# can someone tell me what i am doing wrong with this sql code

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Insert into DonutOrder (Date, Special Handling Notes)
Values ("20140506", "Please Include Plates and Napkins");
```

I keep getting this response
 Error
SQL query:

```
Insert into DonutOrder (Date, Special Handling Notes);
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Handling Notes)' at line 1

Comment: You need square bracket -  [Special Handling Notes]

Comment: whitespace in column names is not allowed. wrap it with backticks or other character depending on the database being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your identifier (column name) has spaces, so you should escape it with backticks:

```
insert into `DonutOrder` (`Date`, `Special Handling Notes`) Values ("20140506", "Please Include Plates and Napkins");
```

Comment: Or rather OP should use sane names for his fields.

Comment: @PeeHaa: Well, yeah, unless it is not his own invention

Comment: Thank you for the information i am now not getting that error code but a different one about foreign key constraints even though i am not trying to update anything in those columns. This is all for a school project i am in the last stages of completing it but having several problems with syntax errors the new error is code 1452 cannot add or update a child row foreign key constraint fails